# Complex query combining

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all, thank you for reading my problem. I am very thankful for the people in the community helping others learn more about coding. As this SQL and PHP is part of my hobby, I am limited by Google and fora where I can find answers to my questions. Unfortunately, I can't find a good answer for a problem encountered.

What am I trying to do?
I run a website where you can note your kilometers and liters you filled your car and see your statistics. I want to do a big search in MySQL with a query. I know how to get the results in multiple queries (3 to be exact), but I need it to be in one single query.

What does my table look look like?
For an example I am using this table to make the problem more visual, it's named '**fillings**' for now.

```
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| tank_id | user_id | kilometers | liters | car_id | date       |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 1       | 2       | 450        | 20     | 2      | 2017-11-01 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 2       | 1       | 500        | 30     | 1      | 2017-12-15 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 3       | 2       | 490        | 25     | 2      | 2017-11-05 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 4       | 3       | 260        | 19     | 3      | 2017-11-07 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 5       | 3       | 610        | 30     | 3      | 2017-12-03 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
| 6       | 3       | 100        | 4      | 3      | 2017-12-07 |
+---------+---------+------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

This is a basic idea of my main table where all the fill-ups are being registrated. In reality someone can have multiple cars, but for now let's asume that a user only has one car.

What are the SQL queries? 
The query that I want to make should have this result:

```
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | consumption november | consumption overall |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| 2       | 20,9                 | 20,9                |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| 1       |                      | 16,7                |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
| 3       | 13,7                 | 18,3                |
+---------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, the fillings of november are taking and a consumption is being calculated. Also, an overall consumption is being calculated of all fillings from a certain type of user. I know how to make this result, devided in two queries. That's:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption overall
FROM fillings
GROUP BY user_id
```

And also the query:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption november
FROM fillings
WHERE 'date'
BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-31'
GROUP BY user_id
```

So right now I want to combine the queries into one, so that I can get the result that I want. Note that in the example, someone can have a null consumption in a month, because hé or she did not fill up their car in that month.

I've looked into the options of UNION and JOIN but I can't seem to find a way to make this working.

I hope everything is clear, and if not, don't hesitate to ask and I will explain in further detail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is possible that the records are not in range within the month, a LEFT JOIN is recommended for the date specific query:

```
 SELECT 
 t1.user_id, t2.consumption_november, t1.consumption_overall 
 FROM (
   SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_overall 
   FROM fillings 
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t1
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_november 
   FROM fillings 
   WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-31'
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t2
 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3fdce84/16

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a lot! What if I wanted to add just one more column with the consumption of the last 3 months, so let's say 2017-09-01 AND 2017-11-31...? I have tried to add another LEFT JOIN as you did in your answer, and I added = t3.user_id to the last line, but that didn't work unfortunately. Of course I also changed the subquery with the exact dates. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2017-11-01' AND date < '2017-12-01'
                 THEN kilometers ELSE 0
            END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN date >= '2017-11-01' AND date < '2017-12-01'
                 THEN liters
            END)
       ) as consumption_november,        
       SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_overall
FROM fillings
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This also works for me, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
SELECT t1.user_id, 
    t1.consumption_overall as consumption overall,
    t2.consumption_november as consumption november
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_overall
    FROM fillings
    GROUP BY user_id
) as t1, (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_november
    FROM fillings
    WHERE 'date'
    BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-31'
    GROUP BY user_id
) as t2
WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

It will take the results of you two queries and put them in the same table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the extended answer (to your question in my first answer, since it's too long to leave as a comment), use :

`SELECT 
t1.user_id, t2.consumption_november, t3.consumption_q, t1.consumption_overall 
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_overall 
   FROM fillings 
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t1
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_november 
   FROM fillings 
   WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-31'
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t2
 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT user_id, SUM(kilometers) / SUM(liters) as consumption_q 
   FROM fillings 
   WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-11-31'
   GROUP BY user_id
 ) t3
 ON t1.user_id = t3.user_id;`

for a subsequent left join, just remove the semicolon from the final left join and extend the pattern, and add the new field in the SELECT clause.